# displaying item on specific listview item only

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I am trying to get a button to show up on my list item (declared as android:visibility:"gone" in the XML) to show as visible when I perform some gestures on it. However, how can I actually notify the getView method correctly to display the button only on the listview item?

---

I tried using getChildAt(position) which ended up displaying several buttons at once.

I tried passing in the position for example I detected that the gesture was performed on from pointToPosition and passed it into the adapter for the getView method to display, but it had the same problem of displaying several at once.

do anyone know how can I solve this?

Comment: What event handler are you using for the Gesture? and which getView method are you referring to?

Comment: @Dan the getView method i was referring to was the one in the adapter class. i made a "self made" gesture method which returns true if such a gesture is performed.

Comment: @Dan basically when the MOTIONEVENT detects an actiondown, i will record it's selected item index through the pointToPosition method. which should be enough for me to identify the id that i need to display the buttons.

Comment: @Dan however the question here is how can i actually use this selected item index to display the button on the selected item only. the above two methods, the getChildAt(position) and customizing the getView method both, displays the button on more items than i require.

Comment: Do you mean you replaced GestureOverlayView with your own gesture interpreter? Could you also paste the code used to create the Adapter?

Comment: @Dan i didn't exactly using the gestureoverlayview for that. it's just some simple conditional statements to determine if the gesture is performed.

Comment: @Dan sorry about the code you requested for. it seems that i have tried different ways of getting it worked out and the code which i described above seems to have been removed.

Comment: @Dan perhaps you could show me how can i actually edit the getView method to display only the item i want in the list? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a misunderstanding of how Adapter.getView() works its meant to create or reuse layouts when rendering the ListView it also needs to be fast so conditional manipulation in this method is discouraged.  Although ListView.getChildAt() may work it does not effectively use the API. Your adapter will have a setViewBinder() unless you're using an ArrayAdapter (if so I suggest using [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) because of the additional features). Use your ViewBinder implementation to switch the visibility of the button.

If you'd prefer to continue to use ArrayAdapter use `ListView.getChildAt(int)` to `findViewById(R.id.your_button).setVisibility()`.  If this is what you already tried and its setting all the buttons visible then please post the related code.

Comment: thanks, i will have to try to see if i can get the code back to the way i did it previously and post the code up if i can. thanks.